# Every prime field of finite characteristic $p$ is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb Z_{p}$ of the residue classes of the set of integers modulo $p$.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

All I know about this is $\Bbb Z_{p}$ is a field of order $p$. Therefore,if $e\neq a \in \Bbb Z_{p}$,then $\vert a \vert =p$.But I'm not getting any idea of how to move further.
Any kind of hints are welcome.

Thank You.

Comment: This is not true: for each $n\geq 1$ there is a field of characteristic $p$ with $p^n$ elements.

Comment: Check again carefully what you want or are asked to prove. The claim in your question is false big time.

Comment: @carmichael561:my bad i've just started field theory.Let me check from reference book.but thank you.

Comment: @DonAntonio:now see.

Comment: Now it is correct...but then there doesn't seem to be much problem: just prove the ring $\;\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ is a field whenever $\;p\;$ is a prime...

Comment: @DonAntonio:I've shown that $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is a field.But how can i show that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{p}$?

Comment: @PKStyles Then you're done as it is the **minimal** possible field of characteristic $\;p\;$ and thus it **is** the prime such field.

Comment: @DonAntonio:Can we do this analytically,like using  mappings or some other stuff?

Comment: @PKStyles What is "it" in your question? If you've shown $\;\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ is a *field* then you've also shown it has characteristic $\;p\;$, and since its size is $\;p\;$ then it is the prime such field. What isn't clear here?

Comment: Any field $k$ of char. $p>0$ is endowed with a unique field morphism $i : \mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}\to k$. This morphism is therefore injective. If $k$'s cardinal is $p$, then the application $i$ must be also surjective as $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ is also of cardinal $p$. The morphism $i$ is therefore an isomorphism. It is an explicit : to the image of $n$ in $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ you associate the image of $n$ in $k$.